# mod_wsgi's WSGIDaemonProcess.threads - what does it control?

Tags: multithreading, apache, thread-safety, mod-wsgi, geodjango

In GeoDjango documentation it mentions that [GDAL is not thread-safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/gis/deployment/) and thus the app should be run in a single thread by setting `WSGIDaemonProcess` attribute `threads` to `1`.

What is the relationship between that setting and Apache's own [MPM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mpm.html) modules? By default my Apache web server is configured to use 2 processes <strike>with automatic thread scaling...</strike> (Graham correctly pointed out below that this is NOT the case). Would setting `WSGIDaemonProcess` force this to no threads, or is this only for controlling forking downstream of MPM module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache doesn't have automatic thread scaling. Apache only has process scaling. The number of threads in each process is fixed, albeit that under worker MPM the number of threads in a process can be greater than 1.

Anyway, what you want is daemon mode of mod_wsgi. You need both WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup (or equivalent). This will see the WSGI application running in a separate set of processes rather than in the Apache worker processes. In your case you would want to set threads to be 1 and processes to some value greater than 1 to still at least give a level of concurrency.

Go read the mod_wsgi documentation and related link blogs and conference talks.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/
- http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/